# Closing the leadbolt app wall with the back button

Tags: android, leadbolt

I am displaying a leadbolt app wall (offer wall) in my main Android activity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mAdAppWall = new AdController(this, getString(R.string.adsAppWall));
mAdAppWall.loadAd();
```

This displays fine, however if I press the back button of the device, my activity is closed. I don't want the activity to close, I just want to close the app wall, like tapping its "x" does.

The leadbolt documentation showed me how to solve this problem for banner ads, which I tried to extend for the offer wall ad like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event)
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        if(mAdController.onBackPressed() || mAdAppWall.onBackPressed())
        {
            if (mAdAppWall.onBackPressed()) {
                mAdAppWall.destroyAd();
            }

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            mAdController.destroyAd();
            mAdAppWall.destroyAd();
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

However, this closes the ad and then immediately reopens it when pressing the back button.

How can I make pressing the back button on the device close the full screen offer wall?